# How to save a table in pyspark sql?

Tags: python, hadoop, save, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to save my resulting table into a csv, textfile or similiar to be able to perform visualization with RStudio.

I am using pyspark.sql to perform some queries in a hadoop setup. I want to save my result in hadoop and then copy the result into my local drive.

```
myTable = sqlContext.sql("SOME QUERIES")
myTable.show() # Show my result
myTable.registerTempTable("myTable") # Save as table
myTable.saveAsTextFile("SEARCH PATH") # Saving result in my hadoop
```

This returns this:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'

This is how I usually do it when using only pyspark i.e. not pyspark.sql.

And then I copy to local drive with

```
hdfs dfs –copyToLocal SEARCH PATH
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrameWriter` with one of the supported formats. For example for JSON:

```
myTable.write.json(path)
```

Comment: Thank you! Work as it should :)
Any idea of get it as csv instead?
I tried myTable.write.csv(path), but it did not work. I am using spark 1.6.